# How would I write an extension method for System.Data.Linq.Table<T>?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, extension-methods

I wanted to write this small, trivial extension method for some throwaway test / console app and I haven't been able to figure out how to get the method signature right.  I'm looking to add this to every System.Data.Linq.Table that I have and I want it to take an instance of type T as a parameter.

Here's what I have so far that doesn't compile

```
public static void InsertAndSubmit<T>(this System.Data.Linq.Table<T> tbl, T element)
{
    tbl.InsertOnSubmit(element);
    tbl.Context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter
>   'TEntity' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Data.Linq.Table'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void InsertAndSubmit<T>(this System.Data.Linq.Table<T> tbl, T element)
    where T : class
{
    tbl.InsertOnSubmit(element);
    tbl.Context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

You need to constrain the type of `T` to be a reference type (`class`) in order for this to work.

If you look at `Table<TEntity>`'s [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx) you will notice this same type constraint on `TEntity` of `class`.  So for your `T` to be compatible with `TEntity` it must meet the same constraints.

Comment: So the only reason I have to specify this on my extension method is because they specify this on their definition?  Thanks!

Comment: Yep.  The compiler sees that your `T` is unconstrained and therefore incompatible with the the constraints specified on `TEntity`.  So you must constrain your type to make the compiler happy that your type is indeed compatible with `TEntity`.

Comment: Brilliant, that makes sense.  I never thought to look in the definition of `Linq.Table` and I was going crazy.  I never realized that constraints carried forward through to extension methods.  Thanks alot!  I'll accept when it lets me

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify that you will use only refernece types in your `T`. Try:

```
public static void InsertAndSubmit<T>(this System.Data.Linq.Table<T> tbl, T element) 
    where T : class
{
    tbl.InsertOnSubmit(element);
    tbl.Context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: ARGH, thanks, I was fairly certain my method signature was correct.  I didn't think it was necessary to specify the type of T